# Bulma columns are not working, how to fix them?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bulma

I am trying to build a Bulma website.

For the purpose of showing and sharing with you, consider the following code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Some App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
   <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false">
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-end">
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Home</a>
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Blah</a>
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Blah</a>
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Blah</a>
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Blah</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
  
  <section class="section">

   <div class="container" style="border: 3px solid red">
    <div class="columns is-centered">
     <div class="column" style="border: 3px solid purple">Auto</div>
     <div class="column" style="border: 3px solid yellow">Auto</div>
     <div class="column is-two-thirds" style="border: 3px solid green">is-two-thirds</div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </section>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When it comes to those columns, they seem not to be working. I wonder what I've missed along the way.

I want the three columns to be three actual columns with some height and some space between each other. However, they are "stacked".

How do I make them behave like real columns?

Comment: When I looked, it seemed to work fine. I did notice you did not include the Bulma CSS file. Is this the cause of your issue? (JSFiddle showing it working: https://jsfiddle.net/Bronzdragon/3cpx1bnj/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included Bulma's CSS file in the code. That is why it does not apply the CSS properties. The code below worked for me perfectly. I only added the CDN reference to bulma's css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Some App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
   <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false">
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-end">
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Home</a>
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Blah</a>
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Blah</a>
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Blah</a>
     <a class="navbar-item has-text-centered">Blah</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
  
  <section class="section">

   <div class="container" style="border: 3px solid red">
    <div class="columns is-centered">
     <div class="column" style="border: 3px solid purple">Auto</div>
     <div class="column" style="border: 3px solid yellow">Auto</div>
     <div class="column is-two-thirds" style="border: 3px solid green">is-two-thirds</div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </section>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```